# The left edge of a sheet protector (punched pocket)

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, american-english, british-english

What is a correct word to refer to the edge of a sheet protector [US] (aka punched pocket [UK]): *edge*, *stripe*, *strip*, *spine*?

The word should be understandable to both US and UK native speakers. (I'm neither.)

[image]

I mean the white thing at the left.

Comment: I don't know that it has a specific name—at least not one that you could use and be understood by as average a reader as I—so you just have to get more specific with your description. "The strip on the edge of the [sheet protector/punched pocket] in which the holes are punched" is a mouthful but leaves no doubt.

Comment: Maybe *margin*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several similar product-description pages that refer to the reinforced strip/side as the **binding edge**. I suggest **punched binding edge**. This, of course, is the edge that goes into a loose-leaf binder.

> Each **binding edge** is 11-hole **punched** to ensure they are compatible
> for any binder or presentation cover. [Google Shopping](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/1?q=plastic%20page%20protectors&prds=epd:9555262494217494467,eto:9555262494217494467_0,pid:9555262494217494467,prmr:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwictY-s-Nf0AhUGRDABHQnXBjwQ9pwGCAc)